# expressjs req.body.username is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I've seen several posts related to this but none seem to be the problem here.

It's a very simple beginner nodejs app with expressjs on windows7

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */


var express = require('express')
    , connect = require('connect')
    , http = require('http')


var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  // app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(connect.bodyParser());
});

/**
 * Routes
 */
//get requests
// app.get("/", function(req, res){
//   res.send("Hello, Express!");
// });

// app.get("/hi", function(req, res){
//   var message = [
//     "<h1>Hello, Express!</h1>",
//     "<p>Welcome to 'Building Web Apps in Node.js with Express.'</p>",
//     "<p>You'll love Express because it's</p>",
//     "<ul><li>Fast</li>",
//     "<li>Fun</li>",
//     "<li>Flexible</li>"
//   ].join("\n");

//   res.send(message);
// });

// app.get("/users/:userID", function(req, res){
//   res.send("<h1>Hello, User #" + req.params.userID + "!");
// });

//post requests
app.post("/users", function(req, res){
    // res.send(req.body);
    res.send(req.body.username);
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

As you can see I've commented out other routes just to ensure they aren't causing the problem and I've also tried installing and using 'connect' but both express.bodyParser() and connect.bodyParser() give me the same results.

I've used chrome adv rest client extension and also tried the following simple php form.

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/users" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <li>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </li>
</form>
```

In all cases I get a empty or undefined req.body.username and when I try just req.body in the response I get a empty object {}

**UPDATE:** 
Here is the response/request header info from chrome:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:31
Host:localhost:3000
Request Payload
username=isimmons&submit=Submit
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 27 Oct 2012 23:01:45 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express
```

And Here is what I get when I send req.route

```
//result of console.log(req.route);
{ path: '/users',
  method: 'post',
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  keys: [],
  regexp: /^\/users\/?$/i,
  params: [] }
```

Node and Express versions:
express 3.0
node 0.8.9

**UPDATE2 PROBLEM SEMI SOLVED**
See comments below. I should have just said it here. Anyway, here is the request header info from chrome when it works correctly.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:26
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/nodeform.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1305.3 Safari/537.16
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:dfd
submit:Submit
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 28 Oct 2012 01:12:23 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Thanks

Comment: You can remove the connect stuff and use express.bodyParser(). Express is a layer on top of connect so you don't need to use it directly. I don't see anything weird with the rest of your code. The only thing I can think of is that because app.configure is causing problems on windows. You can remove app.configure. It's sugar that checks the NODE_ENV and executes the function based on the value.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any obvious issues with your code. What version of Express do you have installed? And, since you mention Chrome, have you [inspected](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) the details of the POST request for the `<form>`, verifying that it lists a value for `username` under "Headers" and "Form Data?"

Comment: @Pickels Yeah I figured out after looking around that connect is already a node_module of express so I removed all of that. But when I remove the configure line for the port I get page not found because it doesn't seem to be defaulting to port 3000.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I've updated the question with express and node versions and some header info. Thanks guys for looking at it

Comment: I would post the answer but I don't really understand this enough to provide an answer. It seems that something is wrong with the chrome rest client extension that is messing things up and then it affects all posts whether using firefox or chrome. After shutting everything down and restarting the node server again, then posting with my php form it worked. Upon testing, things break again when I use the rest client but work if I close everything again. Notice the difference in response headers posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally came across this bug report for the rest api and simply adding the content-type resolved the issue.

[Bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=85)

The bug report has a reply to manually add the 'Content-type' header before sending. This is why the php form worked. It has the enctype set so I get the complete request header as shown above.

The correct content-type header to add manually is

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```